# Protobuf encodes int64 data type to string in json mapping

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a data source of proto serialized messages and I have the .proto file, so I know each field's type to-be.
I deserialize a proto message like this:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
data = MessageToJson(proto_obj, including_default_value_fields=True)
```

The problem is that every int64 field is converted to string type, and it's because of [protobuf json mapping](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json)

I need to jsonize the data, and it's important to me to make the fields with default value present in the data, so I set the flag `including_default_value_fields=True` to consider this.

> If a field has the default value in the protocol buffer, it will be omitted in the JSON-encoded data by default to save space.

The main struggle here is about preventing casting int64 types to string. Does anybody have any solution?
Thank you in advance!

PS: I'm using proto3.

Comment: The JSON standard limits integers to what will fit in 32 bits. So if the int64 were not converted to a string, the result would be invalid JSON.

Comment: Exactly! Do you know any other libraries to parse a proto message into python dictionary or string (other than json) and have an option for `including_default_value_fields`?

Comment: You may have little alternative but to translate such stings coming into Python back into integers. If you already know what fields are involved it only needs a call to `int()` for those.

Comment: @BoarGules that's not true, the json standard places no limit on size of "number" type, only that it is a series of digits with optional decimal and exponent. https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/

Comment: @KeithTyler Conceded that *the JSON standard* was sloppy terminology. JSON Schema distinguishes between the *number* and *integer* types, and JSON Schema limits such *integers* to 32 bits. Because: Transmitting a long Python integer as a JSON *number* runs the risk of having a target system (such as, for example, one written in JavaScript) treat it as a float and so lose precision with no warning. So as a practical matter there needs to be a limit on the size of an integer, whatever the standard might say about *number*s. https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html

Comment: @BoarGules No, that's not what I meant. I don't see anywhere in the actual JSON standard that limits the size of numerical values. What I meant was, Google has written it's *own* alternate JSON standard for Protobuf's purposes that limits the size of numerical values. But that's not *the* JSON standard, that's *Google*'s own special version of it. Google does this because JS implementers apparently can't fix their bugs.
I don't know what you linked to, but that's also not "the" JSON Standard, and I also don't see anywhere on that page that says there is a limit to numeric values.

Comment: @KeithTyler I already admitted that using *the JSON standard* was sloppy terminology.  JSON Schema is also a standard, just not the one I said it was (though for OP's purposes the error was irrelevant because that was the one they were working to). JSON Schema limits the size of *integers* to 32 bits to stop JavaScript mangling *number*s without warning. Most people still think the JS in JSON stands for JavaScript. What you say about JSON *numbers* is true, but there is good reason to regard that as a flaw in the standard.  JavaScript's 32-bit integers are not a bug, but a design decision.

Comment: Ref. https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/219#issuecomment-251250029 "_gRPC gateway follows the serialization rules of proto3 and the proto3 spec says that int64, fixed64, and uint64 are all strings._

_This is the case because of IEEE 754 Double precision which JS implements using a 52 bit mantissa (1 for sign, and 11 for exponent). This means the largest number that JS can represent without losing precision is 2^52._"